# Nonlinear optimization with constraint

Tags: r, optimization, nlopt

Consider the following data frame:

```
A=data.frame(v1=c(4,2,-3,3,-1,3,6,-2), v2=c(3,3,-1,5,-3,-2,-2,-3), v3=c(5,-2,2,2,5,5,4,-4),
              v4=c(-2,-1,3,1,-1,3,2,-5), v5=c(2,-5,4,-4,3,1,1,1))
```

with the following optimization problem:

[image: 1]

where a_i is the i-th row of matrix A.

I tried to solve this with the package `nloptr`. First the objective function:

```
 fct <- function(p) {
        return(sum((as.matrix(A)%*%p<0)*(as.matrix(A)%*%p)^2))
        }
```

Then the constraint:

```
 constraint <- function(p){
               return(p[1]-1)
               }
```

But all solvers that I tried demand a gradient, e.g.:

```
sol <- nloptr(x0=c(1,1,-0.13,-0.5,1.3), eval_f=fct, eval_g_eq=constraint,
 opts=list("algorithm"="NLOPT_LD_SLSQP"))

-> A gradient for the objective function is needed by algorithm NLOPT_LD_SLSQP but was not supplied
```

Is it possible to calculate the gradient of this function, or are there other ways to solve this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't recognize that function as a "constraint". I would have expected some sort of conditional or inequality expression. Perhaps you should describe what it is supposed to achieve in natural language.

Comment: `gnm::gnm` function does not need any starting point to be specified. `gnm` stands for generalized nonlinear models. I suggest it.

Comment: The CRAN page of `gnm`: [link](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gnm/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you can solve this as a standard QP (Quadratic Programming) problem:

```
min sum(i, y(i)^2 )
y(i) <= sum(j, a(i,j)*p(j))
y(i) <= 0
```

No need for gradients. QP Solvers like quadprog, Cplex and Gurobi can solve this: just plug the problem in.

The last constraint is just a bound which simplifies things even more.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I think the sum has to stay outside of  `min(a_i*p,0)^2` as `min(sum(a_i*p,0))` is different from `sum(min(a_i*p,0))`.

Comment: That sum is just the inner product `a_i  p`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time. Unfortunately, I still don't get it.Constraining `a_1 p <= 0, ..., a_8 p <=0` and then minimizing the squared terms seems different from taking the minimum of the squared negative terms.

Comment: You have it really wrong. I don't constrain `a(i)*p`. I just say the variable `y(i)` is less than `min(a(i)*p, 0)`.

Comment: How is `y(i)` defined? I'm not able to transform it into a quadratic function of the parameters p, as p is inside `min(..,0)`.

Comment: You should not transform anything in this formulation.

Comment: But the function `solve.QP()` from `quadprog` has arguments `Dmat` (matrix) and `dvec` (vector). I don't understand how I can plug the suggested solution in there.